# rake invokes a task twice with -m

Tags: ruby, build, rake, rakefile

I'm building a Rakefile which has a diamond dependency,

```
  A
 / \
B   C
 \ /
  D
```

and the Rakefile is as follows.

```
task :default => :a

task :a => [:b, :c] do |t|
  puts "#{t.name}"
end

task :b => :d do |t|
  puts "#{t.name}"
end

task :c => :d do |t|
  puts "#{t.name}"
end

task :d do |t|
  puts "#{t.name}"
end
```

The problem is that `task :d` is invoked twice with the multitask option.

```
$ rake -m
d
d
c
b
a
```

`task :d` is a task which should be called every time I run rake but exactly once in every build.

I considered using filetask but since it actually is a task which sends a signal to a remote server, there's no file generated by this task.

I also tried the following timestamp method but it doesn't make any change.

```
def (task(:d)).timestamp
  if @timestamp
    @timestamp
  else
    @timestamp = Time.now
  end
end
```

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Since rake is regular ruby you could use every normal ruby-technique to ensure that the stuff behind d is only done once.

Actually I tried your example with a quite recent rake version and could not reproduce your problem:

```
> rake --version
rake, version 10.1.0
> rake
d
b
c
a
> rake -m
d
b
c
a
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the prerequisite tasks are run sequentially, does it make sense to just have one dependent task to D from C and not have one from B. This way, you can ensure that both B and C have run before D runs.

Comment: Prereq tasks are not run sequentially, but concurrently if you `rake -m`.

Comment: I would skip concurrent tasks in this case.